# She is doing it!

Tags: expressions, traduction, oral

I am wondering if  there a good way to say **"She is doing it!"** in the sense of cheering someone on.

An example context, to make myself clear:

- 2 swimmers are competing and near the end of the race the commentator says "xxx is doing it!" (xxx is winning the race)

Answer (score 13):

I think those are the closest translations:

- **« Elle/Il va le faire ! »** - *She/He's going to do it!*
- **« Elle/Il va y arriver ! »** - *She/He's going to do it!*
- **« Elle/Il peut le faire ! »** - *She/He can do it!*

Those idioms are often used by commentators, sometimes followed by:

- **« Elle/Il l'a fait !! »** - *She/He's done it!!*

Comment: "Elle/Il va y arriver !" is rendered essentially by "She/He's going to *make* it!